# Powershell - Unable to add specific text in Excel Comobject

Tags: excel, powershell, comobject

I'm attempting to add specific text to a cell in an Excel sheet using Powershell. For example:

```
$1,500/$2,500
```

The closest I can get to adding that text into a cell with the proper formatting is to remove the characters: `1500/2500`. I've tried treating the cell as text and entering it as a formula.

Does not work:

```
$wb.Sheets(1).Range("G9").Formula = "=""$1,500""&""/""&""$2,500"""
```

Or

```
$wb.Sheets(1).Range("G9").NumberFormat = "@"
$wb.Sheets(1).Range("G9").Value = "$1,500/$2,000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double:

```
$wb.Sheets(1).Range("G9").Value = '$1,500/$2,000'
```

You can eliminate the `$wb.Sheets(1).Range("G9").NumberFormat = "@"` as well. It is not necessary to change the cell formatting to text.